# modprobe -r [modules]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[60 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modules) tagged [modules](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modules). Most of them are dealing with [kernel-module](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kernel-module)s. Others talk about Apache2/Perl/Python/Puppet/Drupal/Slax modules. There's even [one](https://superuser.com/questions/432375/are-these-memory-modules-suitable-for-my-computer) about memory modules.

The [modules] tag is useless. Kernel module questions should be tagged with [kernel-module](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kernel-module), other questions should get rid of [modules](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modules).

Comment: Sounds good to me; let's re-tag the kernel ones and remove the others.

Comment: @slhck: There are a number of questions related to modulefiles (http://modules.sourceforge.net/).  Worth a dedicated tag?

Comment: @fixer1234 I've never heard of it—seems a little specifc. But I don't know.

Comment: I'm fine with the relabeling  and  dedicated tag(s) for modules.sourceforge.net

Comment: All 'modules' tags gone to the great tag cloud in the sky :)